# Steam crashes on launch (18.04)

Tags: steam, 18.04

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop.  Then I installed Steam via the website yesterday, and it worked.  When I tried to launch Steam today it simply crashed as the auto-update began.  I used `sudo apt-get purge steam` when uninstalling and have tried to re-install both with the download from the website and with `sudo apt-get install steam`.  The problem persists however.

This is the output I get when trying to run Steam from the terminal:

```
~$ steam
cp: cannot stat '/usr/lib/steam/bootstraplinux_ubuntu12_32.tar.xz': No such file or directory
Running Steam on ubuntu 18.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Pins up-to-date!
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1522709999)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1522709999)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1522709999)
Gtk-Message: 16:31:00.768: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"

...

Gtk-Message: 16:31:00.786: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
dbus[8768]: arguments to dbus_message_new_method_call() were incorrect, assertion "path != NULL" failed in file ../../../dbus/dbus-message.c line 1362.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.

  D-Bus not built with -rdynamic so unable to print a backtrace
crash_20180502163059_1.dmp[8775]: Uploading dump (out-of-process)
/tmp/dumps/crash_20180502163059_1.dmp
/home/magnus/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 927:  8768 Aborted                         (core dumped) $STEAM_DEBUGGER "$STEAMROOT/$STEAMEXEPATH" "$@"
crash_20180502163059_1.dmp[8775]: Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = yes
crash_20180502163059_1.dmp[8775]: response: CrashID=bp-a9833971-19cb-45ce-a771-2cb7f2180502
crash_20180502163059_1.dmp[8775]: file ''/tmp/dumps/crash_20180502163059_1.dmp'', upload yes: ''CrashID=bp-a9833971-19cb-45ce-a771-2cb7f2180502''
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Since the file `/usr/lib/steam/bootstraplinux_ubuntu12_32.tar.xz` is missing, it looks like `steam-launcher` is not installed.  Apparently, the `steam` package has been replaced by `steam-launcher`.

  Try the following to uninstall the old package and install the new one:

  ```
  sudo aptitude purge steam steam:i386
  sudo aptitude install steam-launcher libatk-bridge2.0-0
  ```

  If `steam-launcher` is not available, try installing `steam-installer` instead.

  ```
  sudo aptitude install steam-installer libatk-bridge2.0-0
  ```
- The package `steam-launcher` does not install Steam itself.  Rather, it is a program that downloads and installs Steam into the user's home directory at `$HOME/.local/share/Steam`.  If Steam is already installed, it is run.

  That Steam was interrupted during an update and is now crashing indicates a problem with the installation directory.  You can force a reinstall by moving the installation folder:

  ```
  mv "$HOME/.local/share/Steam" "$HOME/.local/share/Steam.bak"
  mkdir "$HOME/.local/share/Steam"
  cp -rl "$HOME/.local/share/Steam.bak/package" "$HOME/.local/share/Steam/package"
  ```

  Then select the option to "reinstall" when running `steam`.  A few-hundred megabytes of data may need to be downloaded.

  After successfully reinstalling and running Steam, you can look for old games in `$HOME/.local/share/Steam.bak` and move them to the new installation `$HOME/.local/share/Steam`.  If you have nothing you want to move, `$HOME/.local/share/Steam.bak` is safe to delete.
- **Last Resort:** If none of the above fixes the problem, and you don't mind reinstalling Steam from scratch, you can try deleting all Steam-related files from your home directory:

  ```
  \rm -rf $HOME/.steam*
  \rm -rf $HOME/.local/share/Steam*
  ```

Comment: I do not know exactly what those commands did, but now Steam works.
Thanks for both your help and your patience.

Comment: steam-launcher seems not to be part of the default repositories (`E: Unable to locate package steam-launcher`) From where do you have it?

Comment: Steam has its own repositories. To install them, download and install the Steam `deb` from the Steam website.

Answer (score -1):

run this in your terminal

~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam

credit to MaiconKeller on the Steam community forum

Comment: What does that do? How is that supposed to fix the problem?

Comment: Not a solution to the original question.